# Why does my projector only show my desktop background and not the desktop icons?

Tags: laptop, projector

My laptop is connected to a projector. The projector shows my desktop background but none of the icons that are shown on my laptop screen.

Comment: Have you checked the graphics properties are set to "clone" desktop and not to stretch?

Answer (score 17):

Your laptop is probably set to *extend* your desktop onto the projector instead of duplicating it. If you're using Windows, follow [this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/connect-to-a-projector) from Microsoft for how to cycle through the different projector options, or press Windows + P and select Duplicate.

You should see four options that look like this:

[image: projector options]

In Extend mode, you should be able to drag icons or programs back and forth between your laptop's desktop and the projector. In Duplicate mode, your icons, open programs, etc. should show up on both the laptop and the projector.

Comment: to move windows between screens quickly use `win+shift+left/right`

Answer (score 2):

Right Clik on the laptop Desktop -> choose Display Properties -> Then you can see a dropdown -> choose Duplicate displayes.

Curently your projector is connected in Extended mode.

Answer (score 0):

You just right click on desktop  and click on screen resolution  option and set as Duplicate these display

[image]

Comment: No need to do that. `win+P` is enough